# Викторина на подобие игры "Своя Игра"

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

4 участника , один выбирает например : вопрос 100 ,по клику на кнопке 100 появляется окошко с вопрос , на окошке так же 4 кнопки то есть 4 человека 4 кнопки где будут начисляться баллы. Если выбрал вопрос на 100 то начисляется 100 ,если 200 то 200. Нужно написать этот код сложения или как там начисление баллов.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Какие у вас возникли затруднения при написании кода?

Comment: Я не знаю как начислять баллы

Comment: @Timur3250, сохраняйте их в переменную

Comment: Допустим я синий вы красный один желтый четвертый серый , я выбрал вопрос на 100 и при нажатии на синюю кнопку надо чтобы начислили на мою синюю кнопку 100 ,потом если еще отвечу добавляется смотря на сколько очков выбран ответ

Comment: Покажите на примере

Comment: А если быллы сделать input[type="radio"] и из них брать соответствующее значение - это для логики начисления баллов

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример с input button

```js
v = 0;
cur = 0;

val = document.querySelector('.val');
get = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.get'));
get.forEach(function(e, i) {

  e.onclick = function(e) {
    get.forEach(function(s) {s.style='background: #E0E4E8';});
    this.style = 'background: #FFE4E8';
    cur = this.value;
  }

});

document.querySelector('.update').onclick = function() {
  v = parseInt(cur) + parseInt(v);
  val.innerHTML = 'Баллы: ' + v.toString();

}
```

```css
.get {
  background: #E0E4E8;
  border: 0px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div class='val'>Баллы: 0</div>

<input class='get' type='button' value='100'>
<input class='get' type='button' value='200'>
<input class='get' type='button' value='300'>
<input class='get' type='button' value='400'>
<input class='get' type='button' value='500'>

<input class='update' type='button' value='Правильный ответ'>
```

Пример с input radio

```js
v = 0;
cur = 0;

val = document.querySelector('.val');
get = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.get'));
get.forEach(function(e, i) {

  e.onclick = function(e) {
    cur = this.value;
  }

});

document.querySelector('.update').onclick = function() {
  v = parseInt(cur) + parseInt(v);
  val.innerHTML = 'Баллы: ' + v.toString();

}
```

```html
<div class='val'>Баллы: 0</div>

<label><input class='get' type='radio' value='100' name='get'>100</label>
<label><input class='get' type='radio' value='200' name='get'>200</label>
<label><input class='get' type='radio' value='300' name='get'>300</label>
<label><input class='get' type='radio' value='400' name='get'>400</label>
<label><input class='get' type='radio' value='500' name='get'>500</label>

<input class='update' type='button' value='Правильный ответ'>
```

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
//Модальное окно
function show(state)
{
document.getElementById('window').style.display = state;
document.getElementById('wrap').style.display = state;
}
</script>   а кнопки у меня такие <button onclick="show('block')">100</button>

Comment: на input скрипт окна не работает

Comment: @Timur3250, в чём проблема переделать input на button? Я не вижу всего кода, нужно было предоставить его в вопросе

Comment: Напиши для кода который ты написал еще и код для всплывающего окна

Comment: @Timur3250, это к вопросу уже не относится. Ты хочешь чтобы я за тебя всё сделал? Тогда ты ошибся сайтом, здесь не принимаются ТЗ. Приложи свои усилия